# Saving data into the program?

Tags: c, save

Is it possible for one portable program to keep save data inside the application?
I don't want the program to create folders or files.

Comment: You could use a database

Comment: @usar Which means host it in a server..
I don't think i can afford such a responsibility..

Comment: Do you need to persist data across application restarts? If so you do need some sort of file system storage.

Comment: @metacubed I've heard you could use the executable by itself to store data. It might be a bit tricky.

Comment: It would not be practical to modify the exe itself to store runtime data. Most portable apps use an .ini file in the same folder as the .exe, or they use the registry.

Comment: It couldn't be registry keys since they are actual folders with files.
Maybe it is a service running?

Comment: Ehh... i just added `1` at the very end of a "Hello World" executable via Hex Editor and the application still works as expected. And it appears.. it works with `154` as well.

Comment: Take a look at this question: [Save data in executable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661516/save-data-in-executable). It is for C# but the answers are not C# specific.

Comment: They says it cannot be modified.. but i just simply did.

Comment: A nice way of saving is using `tmpfile`

Comment: The appending will work only if the exe is unsigned. Most professional applications are signed - appending will corrupt the exe in that scenario. And `tmpfile` creates a temporary file, usually in `%TMP%`.

Comment: It's a good question. If your program is written by some scripting language such as python, I think it would be easy to solve your problem by just rewriting itself (just keep the data in some variables). However, if it isn't written by that kind of language, it would be difficult and I am also looking forward to an elegant solution.

Comment: I have tested a couple of different executables.. as metacubed pointed out they appears to be "unsigned" since i can easy store data at the end of the byte quoue.

Comment: Why would you like to change the executable file?  Using another file, or an external database, is the way to go.

Comment: Because it is waaay more secure in a lot of aspects, it is portable and seems to be a good practice. When one programmer improvise, then he show how good is he.

Comment: How about Registry (if your software using Windows)?

Comment: What if not using Windows?
Registry keys are files that can be easily exploited by cheap viruses.
Thats what i talk about. Even PUP software can play with the registry keys (Microsoft is lame)

Comment: Mutating executables are going to be a problem for AV software, if not an actual security risk:(

Answer (score 1):

In order to do it in a portable way, you should have no assumptions about the architecture or operating system: you may or may not have access to the executable in the first place (it could be `argv[0]`, but maybe it isn't. If you had access to the executable file, you could have the rights to open the file and modify it, but maybe you cannot do it.

If, anyway, you want to try it, you could:

- Check if `argv[0]` is a file, that you have read and write permission, and if it is really your code (looking for a random string you can leave somewhere in your code, for example).
- Choose a string to mark your modifications, for example, "Edenia", and check if the last bytes of that file are those.  If so, the file has been previously modified, and you can read your data process it.
- When you want to store additional data, add it to the end of the file (if it was not modified yet), or substitute the modifications it had.  Don't forget to add the mark at the end of the file ("Edenia", or whatever).

Anyway, I still think this is not the proper way to store data: try to use external storage (files, database, etc) if you can.

Comment: I am not asking for any "proper" method. I am asking for something particular. However if your answer is correct, it is rich and i +1 it.